# Creating cursor rsrc files on Mac from png

Tags: macos, png, rsrc

I want to create cursor rsrc files on the Mac from png files. The application that uses the cursors requires it to be in a .rsrc format and I cannot change that. Does anybody know of any way I can create the cursor .rsrc files from png images.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Rezilla](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/23349) to edit resource files on Mac OS X, it has a CURS (and crsr) editor among others. It's a PowerPC binary but it runs well under rosetta on intel.

Also, you don't create a CURS resource file, you create a resource file and add as many CURS resources to it as you need. Resource forks are generic and can contain any number/kind of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a long time since I've thought about MacOS resource forks. Are you using the classic MacOS (i.e. before MacOS X)?

As I recall, [ResEdit](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos8/DevTools/ResEditReference/reseditreference.html) was the application most often used to manipulate the resource fork of a classic Mac application. I know it can edit cursor resources, but I don't recall if it can read PNG files. You may need to convert the files to GIF.

ResEdit is a Classic MacOS application. MacOS X prior to 10.5 could run Classic apps in emulation, but in 10.5 this support has been removed. You'd need to find a system either running the classic MacOS directly, or running 10.4 with Classic installed.

Answer (score 0):

According to this link http://www.macfixit.com/article.php?story=20060621071707921 I need to have a Power PC Mac to run Mac classic. Is this right? I have a Intel Mac running Mac OS 10.4.11 . Are there any other tools capable of running on Intel Mac and could help me create CURS rsrc files. I tried using ResKnife but it didnt seem to have an option to create CURS rsrc files.

Answer (score 0):

If by .rsrc file you mean a standard Mac resource file, you can use the [Resource Manager](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/mac/MoreToolbox/MoreToolbox-9.html#HEADING9-0) to save the image in a file of the appropriate format.